# File created through Intellij IDEA not show on window's file system

Tags: intellij-idea

I have been used Intellij for couple years, recent I found a weird thing, I use Maven to auto import my dependencies, and Maven downloads all libraries and put under "~.m2\repository\" folder, when I open that folder using window file explorer, the folder is not exist. I manually create that folder, it's empty. but if I right click on the project in Intellij IDEA, and click "show in explorer", then go to "~.m2\repository\" folder, I can see all libraries there, and the folder is a little slow to open, seems like it's from some network storage.

any idea?

Thanks

Comment: any body know any intellij plugin may cause this?

Comment: What OS do you use? Does it help if you override the repository folder in IntelliJ IDEA Maven settings?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Windows, I did override it, it shows, but some files created by Intellij still not show. looks like there are two file systems. but sometime they did sync.  if I click "show in explorer" on Intellij, those files I browse are showing slow. seems like from network location.

Comment: Try to change the location to the local directory like `c:\m2`.